# How to write anonymous functions in R arrow across

Tags: r, dplyr, apache-arrow, across

I have opened a .parquet dataset through the `open_dataset` function of the `arrow` package. I want to use `across` to clean several numeric columns at a time. However, when I run this code:

```r
start_numeric_cols = "sum"
sales <- sales %>% mutate(
  across(starts_with(start_numeric_cols) & (!where(is.numeric)), 
         \(col) {replace(col, col == "NULL", 0) %>% as.numeric()}),
  across(starts_with(start_numeric_cols) & (where(is.numeric)),
         \(col) {replace(col, is.na(col), 0)})
)
#> Error in `across_setup()`:
#> ! Anonymous functions are not yet supported in Arrow
```

The error message is pretty informative, but I am wondering whether there is any way to do the same only with `dplyr` verbs within `across` (or another workaround without having to type each column name).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arrow` has a growing set of functions that can be used without pulling the data into R (available [here](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/reference/acero.html)) but `replace()` is not yet supported.  However, you can use `ifelse()`/`if_else()`/`case_when()`.  Note also that purrr-style lambda functions are supported where regular anonymous functions are not.

I don't have your data so will use the `iris` dataset as an example to demonstrate that the query builds successfully, even if it doesn't make complete sense in the context of this data.

```
library(arrow)
library(dplyr)

start_numeric_cols <- "P"

iris %>%
  as_arrow_table() %>%
  mutate(
    across(
    starts_with(start_numeric_cols) & (!where(is.numeric)),
    ~ as.numeric(if_else(.x == "NULL", 0, .x))
  ),
  across(
    starts_with(start_numeric_cols) & (where(is.numeric)),
    ~ if_else(is.na(.x), 0, .x)
  )
)

Table (query)
Sepal.Length: double
Sepal.Width: double
Petal.Length: double (if_else(is_null(Petal.Length, {nan_is_null=true}), 0, Petal.Length))
Petal.Width: double (if_else(is_null(Petal.Width, {nan_is_null=true}), 0, Petal.Width))
Species: dictionary<values=string, indices=int8>

See $.data for the source Arrow object
```

Comment: That worked great! For other users, you can also use the pipe within the `across` `.fns` argument in `arrow`, which I first left as 
`~ifelse(.x == "NULL", 0, .x) %>% as.numeric())`. Although for this particular case I think the output is identical. Thanks also for the link to implemented functions in arrow, it is really useful.

Comment: Just a small comment, when doing what was suggested in the first edit (i.e.: `~ifelse(.x == "NULL", 0, as.numeric(.x))`) I did not get any errors until calling `compute`, which returned `Error in compute():
! Invalid: Failed to parse string: 'NULL' as a scalar of type double`. This last alternative of wrapping the `if_else` statement with `as.numeric` does work.

Comment: @AlbertoAgudoDominguez - that's good to know.  I was unable to test but realized that doing the coercion inside the ifelse statement could cause issues (as well as being bad practice).